ASP.NET Core 8.0 with Angular 18 . Proxy is ready but cannot find api controllers
I have upgraded from Angular 17 to Angular 18. I am now using standalone components with lazy load routing. The ASP.NET Core 8.0.6 did not change.
When I start up Angular with
npm start   ("start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",) in package.json

I can see all the chunk files being created. I can see the following:
  Local:   http://localhost:4200/

Then I start Visual Studio 2022. In the command window I can see the following:
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/ - null null
**SPA proxy is ready**. Redirecting to http://localhost:4200.
Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/ - 302 0 null 70.4862ms

All the html, chunk files , images ..etc are loaded. I can enter user id in login page.
My first API (HTTP POST) call to
http://localhost:4200/api/CoOwner/GetCoOwnerByEmail

returns a error 404
I tried other HTTP GET requests and none of them can access the controller.
I also tried to execute Visual Studio as administrator

When I deploy to a test server (without visual studio) everything works!!

Can you share your proxy.conf.js? The api url should be added there

api url  http://localhost:4200/api/CoOwner/GetCoOwnerByEmail

var onProxyRes = function (proxyRes, req, res) {
var key = 'www-authenticate';
proxyRes.headers[key] = proxyRes.headers[key] &&
proxyRes.headers[key].split(',');
};
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
{
target: "http://localhost:5000",
context: "/",
secure: false,
changeOrigin: true,
loglevel: "debug",
onProxyRes: onProxyRes,
agent: keepaliveAgent
}
];
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;

How Can I send your the proxy,config.js and launchSetting,json (from vs project)?

How Can I send your the - you cannot send - but you can post them here by editing your question, and properly formatting those config files
